# Mediation regression

Tags: regression, categorical-encoding, mediation

I am trying to find the relationship between audit partner rotation on audit quality mediated by audit fees. My third hypothesis which tests the mediation is this: DA = b0 +b1*PROT + b2*LNAUFEE. DA is discretionary accruals,PROT is partner rotation and LNAUFEE is Audit fee. Futhermore, I want to test whether the mechanism(mediation)is different for big 4 and non-big 4 firms hence include a dummy variable BIG4. That is where I get stuck. To test that, should I include an interaction? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would go for multigroup analysis. It is not clear how or where in your model the interaction should take place.